# Don't remember which program I removed(in VS 2015):

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

Short story:
I'm working on Visual Studio 2015, with dotnet core.
I accidently removed some program and now I can't get anything to run on Visual studio. When I try to open my code through VS, it says: "The application is not installed"
or "load failed" and "Incompatible".
Do you know what I might have removed?

Long story:
I tried to make my program work on linux 16.04, and because I had the 1.0.0-preview of DotNet Core(that gave me trouble with tasks in the program that kept on failing on linux), I decided to upgrade, so I installed dotnet-1.1.2, but it kept "coming back" to the old version(meaning, that dotnetcore 1.1.2, is not the main one), no matter how many times I've tried to install or "repair" the new dotnet.

I'd be glad to hear ideas.
Thank you all :)

Comment: VS 2015 does not support .Net Core SDK 1.0.0 or newer. You will need VS 2017 for that.